# Holo theme - different text size in EditText and Spinner

Tags: android, styling, font-size

I have a problem with text sizes of `EditText` and `Spinner` with the default light **Holo** theme. For some reason, they are not the same by default.

Suppose I have this sample layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="EditText default" />

    <EditText
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="EditText spinner style" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@android:array/imProtocols" />
</LinearLayout>
```

... which results in this:

[image]

From the screenshot you can see that:

1. The text size in the  `Spinner` (3) is by default a bit **smaller** than in the `EditText` (1).
2. If I apply `Spinner` style to an `EditText` (2), then it's font has the same "smaller" size as the Spinner.
3. The `Spinner`-styled `EditText` also doesn't have any **left padding** for some reason.

### What I want to achieve

I have created a custom date-time-picker component that derives from `RelativeLayout` and contains two `EditText`s. Upon clicking, the first one displays a date-picker dialog and the second one displays a time-picker dialog.

Now, I would like to style these two `EditText`s to like like a `Spinner`, in a similar fashion to ICS **Google Calendar**, which looks like this:

[image]

The second line is an `EditText` for the *Location* of the event. I have entered the same date value into it as in the *From* input, which is some type of View (probably also an EditText) that displays a DatePickerDialog upon click.

As you can see, the text sizes in the *From* and *To* inputs are the same as in the location `EditText` and also the left padding is the same.

**How can I achieve a Spinner-like appearance for an EditText while maintaining the same font size and left-padding?**

**Where (in the android style XML files) can I find what are the actual default values of textSize, padding etc. of various views and widgets (EditText and Spinner in this case)?**

Comment: You can find all of the base XMLs are in `android-sdk/platforms/android-NN/data/res/`. If it's only a question of styling (font size, padding, margins) it will be easy, but I seem to recall that the actual *image resources* for the EditText and Spinner don't have the same dimensions, which is why they don't align. Or maybe it was the Button and the Spinner.

Comment: @dmon Yes, I know where the SDK XML files are actual on the hard drive, but I was rather looking for the concrete files and <style> elements that define these said attributes. I wasn't very successful in navigating through all the style inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Same for me...

Comment: @user1365836 Well, I manually set `paddingLeft` to `12dp` and `textAppearance` to `?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse` and it seems to look OK, it's not the best possible solution of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, since nobody else answered, this is what I have done:

I've applied the trial and error method to determine the actual text size and left padding of the EditText and then manually set these parameters:

```
<style name="PickerEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
</style>
```

It's a dirty solution, but it seems to work even for different text size settings in the system, so for now I'm sticking with it.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/res/layout/date_picker.xml

Above link is exactly how they do it. Very similar to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13691167). I would even go a different route than they did in the actual app, more like the accepted answer.